# Chef: How I get file content to a variable ,but file do not exist yet

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, recipe

I need to get a file content in a file that I will create.
**My code:**

```
     execute "foo" do
         command "echo "Hello World > /tmp/foo"
         action :run 
end

variable = shell_out!("cat /tmp/foo").stdout
```

**Erro**

```
ERROR: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of cat /tmp/foo ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: cat: /tmp/foo: No such file or directory
---- End output of cat /tmp/foo ----
Ran cat /tmp/data.uuid returned 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Chef's two-pass model, which I detail in https://coderanger.net/two-pass/. Unfortunately you do not give enough detail here to advise on a specific solution but roughly you need to move the `shell_out!()` call in to somewhere not evaluated at compile time.